# Using list of queues in a list

Tags: python, list, queue, list-comprehension

```py
    num_of_stacks = int((len(config[0]) + 1)/4)
    stacks = [Queue() for i in range(num_of_stacks)]
    # stacks = list(map(Queue, range(num_of_stacks)))
    print(stacks)
    for line in config[len(config)-2::-1]:
        print(stacks)
        for i in range(0, len(line), 4):
            print(int(i/4), line[i+1: i+2])
            if line[i+1: i+2] != ' ':
                print(stacks[int(i/4)])
                stacks[int(i/4)].put(line[i+1: i+2])
        print(line)
```

I am writing a program to solve newest Advent of code challange.

Tried to create a list of queues like this:

```py
stacks = list(map(Queue, range(num_of_stacks)))
```

While iterating over it my whole program freezes. On the other hand, creating list of queues using list comprehension resolves the issue:

```py
stacks = [Queue() for i in range(num_of_stacks)]
```

Input example:

```
                [M]     [W] [M]    
            [L] [Q] [S] [C] [R]    
            [Q] [F] [F] [T] [N] [S]
    [N]     [V] [V] [H] [L] [J] [D]
    [D] [D] [W] [P] [G] [R] [D] [F]
[T] [T] [M] [G] [G] [Q] [N] [W] [L]
[Z] [H] [F] [J] [D] [Z] [S] [H] [Q]
[B] [V] [B] [T] [W] [V] [Z] [Z] [M]
 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
```

Does anyone can explain why two codes, that while debugging returns same objects, works differently in case of putting data inside queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two expressions aren't equivalent:

```
stacks = list(map(Queue, range(num_of_stacks)))
stacks = [Queue() for i in range(num_of_stacks)]
```

because `map` calls the function *with the elements of the iterable* as an argument.  So the equivalent list comprehension to your `map` call would be:

```
stacks = [Queue(i) for i in range(num_of_stacks)]
```

You didn't provide the code for your `Queue` class, but I'm inferring that it does something bad when you pass an argument to its constructor.

Comment: Aside: this example makes an excellent case for why using generator expressions or list comprehensions is generally preferred over `map` -- it's much easier in a list comprehension to see what is actually being executed without having to mentally visualize the effects of the `map` call!